# Abrir una aplicación extrema con parametros en la linea de comandos

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la cual necesito abrir una aplicación externa que para poder ejecutarse necesita parámetros en la línea de comandos pero me sale un error de que no encuentra la ruta, ahora si pongo la ruta sin intentar añadirle parámetros si abre pero no ejecuta la función que necesito ya que se tiene que hacer en automático con los parámetros

Tienen alguna manera de ejecutar dicha aplicación con parámetros??
Esto es lo que he probado:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process p = Process.Start("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\App.exe" + param1 + param2);
}
```

Gracias...

Comment: Process tiene una propiedad arguments... la viste??

Comment: @gbianchi aun no, como seria la sentencia??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está dado porque los parámetros deben ir en el segundo parámetro del método, y estar separados por espacio:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process p = Process.Start("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\App.exe", param1 + ' ' + param2);
}
```

Saludos.